# Method with no return type: -()foo

Tags: objective-c, methods, return-value

I searched, but couldn't find a question about this.

I was surprised to find that you can declare a method with an empty return type:

```
- ()foo:(int)bar
{
    return @"baz";
}
```

but that the compiler complains if you don't return something. Without the line `return @"baz"`, the compiler says `"Control reaches end of non-void function"`. This code (without even the parentheses) seems to be the same:

```
- foo:(int)bar
{
    return @"baz";
}
```

How come these kinds of methods work? Is the return type being implied by the return of the method body? I assumed that it would be a syntax error to have a method without any return type.

Answer (score 2):

No. It's just that it's implicitly assumed to be `id`. That's why the compiler complains. The same is true for aguments, by the way (not specifying an explicit argument type results in it being assumed to be `id`).

[Live demo of what I am talking about.](http://ideone.com/ts6peO)

Also, [ancient Apple code](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-208/runtime/Object.m) uses this horrible notation too.

Comment: Thank you, it's good to know not only how this works, but that it was used like this in the past.

Comment: When ObjC was first conceived, the notion was very much all about chaining objects together and using lots of introspection to adjust behaviors.   This proved to be unmanageable and OpenStep moved away from that notion to one that uses `void` return types as default and explicit types for most, but not all, things.  (I.e. @H2CO3 is right-- just adding some color because I'm old and was there).

Comment: @bbum That's very interesting.  I always though the migration away from returning self was for better integration with distributed objects.